# How to specify multiple python files in a PySpark application?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark app (one python file) which does something. I am submitting  this app to spark using spark-submit and passing the dependencies and jars manually (I am not building a Uber Jar).

But as my python file was big and difficult to manage, I split it into multiple .py files under one package (working in PyCharm). Now how do I specify all these files at spark-submit to let it know that all these files together make the application?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Build and distribute egg file.

Comment: You can combine all these dependencies into a `zip` or `egg` file and then pass it as an argument to `--py-files`, while submitting your Spark Job.

Comment: @zero323 Thanks for your comment. For suppose I split my file into 4 chunks (.py files) of which one is the driver file (where I create SparkContext) and the other three have functions and other stuff in them that I will be referring to in the driver file. Could you please explaining it in brief of how to build the zip/egg file and also should I have all the files in the zip/egg or is it just the three .py files (not including driver)? I'm fairly new to this stuff in python and that too on Windows, please bear with me.

Comment: @KarthikKannapur Thanks for your input Karthik. Do you mind sharing a sample of how the spark-submit command should look like? Because as stated in the above comment, I am confused whether to have all of them in the zip/egg file. If I should have all the four files in the egg, how do I specify the main .py in spark submit?

Comment: @avrsanjay How did you layout your project, as I get a module not found error when I try to run spark within pycharm. All files in same spackage.